# Vue JS , GLTF Loader Error "currently no loaders are configured"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, three.js, gltf

Im trying to load a gltf into a vue project.Here is my code

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';

let scene,camera,renderer;

function init(){

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xdddddd);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,1,5000);


    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


    let loader = new GLTFLoader();

    loader.load(require('../../assets/tshirt/gitF/tshirt.glb'),function(gltf){
        //some code here 
}

init();
```

I keep getting the error

```
./src/assets/tshirt/gitF/tshirt.glb 1:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

What am I doing wrong here?
PS: Im new to both VUE and Three.js. I have tried this exact code without a framework and it works. The error only occurs when the code is run in VUE.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `require()` in the load call, and your function parenthesis aren't closing properly:

```
init() {
    //...
    loader.load('../../assets/tshirt/gitF/tshirt.glb',function(gltf){
            //some code here 
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try without require  and still got the same result. P.S. the paranthesis are wrong here because i removed some code to post this here.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that yor webpack.config.js file allows .glb-files among
asset/resource. This solved the problem for me.

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    module: {
        rules: [
            ...
            {
                test: /\.(glb)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

You can read more on at https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/